# Um dos comandos fgets() não é executado

Tags: c

O código roda normalmente até que chega na parte onde é pedido pra inserir as unidades do componente. Eu não inseri nada e ele já encerra o programa.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

//estruturas de dado
struct componente{
    char tipo[20],referencia[4],unidade[10];
    unsigned char num_ref;
    int valor;
}comp/*,comp1,comp2 */;

//struct componente comp;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        printf("\n\n**********CADASTRAR COMPONENTE***********\n");  
    printf("Tipo do componente _ ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(comp.tipo,20,stdin);

    printf("Referência do componente _");
    fgets(comp.referencia,4,stdin);

    printf("Número de referência do componente _");
    scanf("%c",&comp.num_ref);
    //getchar();

    printf("Valor do componente_ ");
    scanf("%d",&comp.valor);

    printf("Unidades _ ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(comp.unidade,10,stdin);

    printf("\n\n**********COMPONENTE CRIADO***********\n"); 
    printf("*Tipo do componente:%s",comp.tipo);
    printf("*Referência do componente:%s",comp.referencia);
    printf("*Número de referência do componente:%c",comp.num_ref);
    printf("*Valor do componente:%d",comp.valor);
    printf("*Unidade: %s",comp.unidade);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: o número de referência tem letras ou só números? se tiver apenas números é mais fácil usar o scanf("%d")

Comment: Sobrou um '\n' no buffer de entrada após a leitura de comp.num_ref. Limpe o buffer antes da leitura.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.
Acrescentei um getchar() depois de ler comp.valor e também coloquei um fflush(stdin) antes de ler comp.referencia.

Comment: Apenas fique ciente que o fflush(stdin) tem comportamento indefinido dependendo do sistema operacional utilizado.

Comment: Não sabia disso. Vou pesquisar sobre

Comment: Veja as questões 12.26a e 12.26b de http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/.